# z-index not working on span with :before

Tags: css

How to put the :before behind the span? I know I did this before but  I can't remember how.
Here's the fiddle.

**HTML**

```
<span>Stack Overflow</span>
```

**CSS**

```
span{
background:#000;
position:relative;
color:#fff;
z-index:20;
}
span:before{
content:'';
background:#000;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
bottom:-10px;
width:20px;
height:20px;
z-index:1;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9FkF/1/)

Comment: try - (negative) in z-index

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`z-index` is relative, so for the `:before` pseudo-element to appear underneath its parent `<span>`, you can specify a z-index of `-1`:

```
span:before{
    content:'';
    background:#000;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    bottom:-10px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w9FkF/2/)

Comment: Glad to help, you might like to accept the answer if it helped :)